# Why are the vector stores I generate via langchain FAISS from_documents always ~4.8 GB in size?

Tags: python, embeddings

I am working on a small application to query a set of PDF documents. Specifically, I am aiming to provide the same query to each document in parallel, not to all documents as a whole.

I have utilized [`langchain.vectorstores.faiss.FAISS.from_documents`](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain.vectorstores.faiss.FAISS.html?highlight=from_documents#langchain.vectorstores.faiss.FAISS.from_documents) to build the vector store for each document after generating the embeddings with [Hugging Face's InstrcutOR XL](https://huggingface.co/hkunlp/instructor-xl/tree/main). Further, prior to generating the embeddings I have split each document with `RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter` with varying chunk sizes and overlaps.

No matter the size of the chunks I always end up with a vector store (well a pickle file with the vector store and some small associated metadata) of ~4.8GB in size. Also, it seems regardless of the original file size the vector store is again 4.8GB.

I have to assume that the vector store database is initialized to this size by default. Though, I cannot find any documentation about changing this size, or reducing it.

**Why are the vector stores I create in this manner always ~4.8GB in size?**

---

For reference, a SSCCE:

```
import os
import glob
import pickle
from tqdm import tqdm
from typing import List

from langchain.schema import Document
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS, VectorStore
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, DirectoryLoader


class DocumentIngestor:

    def __init__(self, input_path: str = r'', store_path: str = r'', embed_model_path: str = r'', chunk_size: int = 2048, chunk_overlap: int = 256, verbose: bool = True):
        self.store_path: str = store_path
        self.input_path: str = input_path
        self.embed_model_path: str = embed_model_path
        self.chunk_size: int = chunk_size
        self.chunk_overlap: int = chunk_overlap
        self.verbose: bool = verbose

        self.sources: List[str] = []                # The file paths of the documents
        self.documents: List[List[Document]] = []   # A single PDF will be parsed as multiple documents, one per page
        self.doc_chunks: List[List[Document]] = []  # After splitting, we will have many Documents per page
        self.vector_stores: List[VectorStore] = []  # After embedding, this is the vector store of them

    def __repr__(self):
        ret = f'\nDocument Ingestor\n'
        ret += f'  Store Path: {self.store_path}\n'
        ret += f'  Input Path: {self.input_path}\n'
        ret += f'  Model Path: {self.embed_model_path}\n'
        ret += f'  Chunk - Size: {self.chunk_size} Overlap: {self.chunk_overlap}\n'
        ret += f' Sources  : {len(self.sources)}\n'
        ret += f' Documents: {len(self.documents)}\n'
        ret += f' Chunks   : {len(self.doc_chunks)}\n'
        ret += f' Stores   : {len(self.vector_stores)}\n'
        return ret

    def load_documents(self):
        if self.verbose: print(f'> Loading documents: {self.input_path}')
        # Load all PDF documents from a directory
        loader = DirectoryLoader(self.input_path, glob="./*.pdf", loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
        raw_documents = loader.load()
        if self.verbose: print(f'  Raw Documents: {len(raw_documents)}')

        # Associated documents from the same source (file path) together
        self.sources = list(set([d.metadata['source'] for d in raw_documents]))  # Set of sources (i.e. file paths)
        for source in self.sources:
            pages = [d for d in raw_documents if d.metadata['source'] == source]
            self.documents.append(pages)
        if self.verbose:
            print(f'  Sources: {len(self.sources)}')
            print(f'  Documents: {len(self.documents)}')

        # Split the text of each document individually.
        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=self.chunk_size, chunk_overlap=self.chunk_overlap)
        for doc_pages in tqdm(self.documents, 'Splitting Documents...'):
            # Assume the text splitter loads all text in all pages and splits across pages.
            self.doc_chunks.append(text_splitter.split_documents(doc_pages))
        if self.verbose:
            print(f'  Document Chunks: {len(self.doc_chunks)}')
            print(f' Done loading documents.')

    def generate_embeddings(self):
        if self.verbose: print(f'> Generating embeddings: {self.embed_model_path}')
        # The embedding model itself
        if self.verbose: print(f'  Loading Model...')
        hfie = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(cache_folder=self.embed_model_path, model_name="hkunlp/instructor-xl", model_kwargs={"device": "cuda"})

        for doc_ind, _ in tqdm(enumerate(self.documents), 'Embedding Documents...'):
            # Build a VectorStore (FAISS is a subclass of VectorStore) of this document's text chunks
            chunks = self.doc_chunks[doc_ind]
            doc_store = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, hfie)
            self.vector_stores.append(doc_store)

        if self.verbose:
            print(f'  Vector Stores: {len(self.vector_stores)}')
            print(f' Done embedding documents.')

    def serialize_embeddings(self):
        if self.verbose: print(f'> Serializing embeddings: {self.store_path}')
        # Create the directory that we will write to
        faiss_dir = f'chunk_size{self.chunk_size}_overlap{self.chunk_overlap}'
        faiss_dir = os.path.join(self.store_path, faiss_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(faiss_dir):
            os.mkdir(faiss_dir)
        if self.verbose: print(f'  Directory: {os.path.basename(faiss_dir)}')

        for doc_ind, doc_pages in tqdm(enumerate(self.documents), 'Serializing Embeddings...'):
            # Get the information that we will store with each embedding
            source = self.sources[doc_ind]
            chunks = self.doc_chunks[doc_ind]
            store = self.vector_stores[doc_ind]
            filename = os.path.basename(source)

            # Create a dict of this information to pass into pickle
            doc_entry = {
                'source': source,
                'filename': filename,
                'chunks': chunks,
                'store': store
            }

            # Build a useful filename and subdirectory
            entry_name = f'[{filename.replace(".pdf", "")}].faiss'
            entry_path = os.path.join(faiss_dir, entry_name)

            # Serialize this documents entry
            with open(entry_path, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(doc_entry, f)

        if self.verbose: print(f' Done serializing embeddings.')

        return faiss_dir

    @staticmethod
    def deserialize_embeddings(serialize_path: str, verbose: bool = True):
        if verbose: print(f'> Deserializing Embeddings: {serialize_path}')
        # Parse the entry_dir and store_path from the serialize_path
        store_path, entry_dir = os.path.split(serialize_path)

        print(f'store_path: {store_path}')
        print(f'entry_dir: {entry_dir}')

        # Extract chunk_size and chunk_overlap from the entry_dir
        entry_tokens = entry_dir.split('_')
        chunk_size = int(entry_tokens[1].replace('size', ''))
        chunk_overlap = int(entry_tokens[2].replace('overlap', ''))
        if verbose:
            print(f'  Store Path: {store_path}')
            print(f'  Chunk - Size: {chunk_size} Overlap: {chunk_overlap}')

        # Instantiate a DocumentIngestor object with the parsed information
        di = DocumentIngestor(input_path='', store_path=store_path, embed_model_path='', chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)

        # Use glob to find all .faiss files in the directory
        faiss_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(serialize_path, '*.faiss'))
        if verbose: print(f'  File Count: {len(faiss_files)}')

        for faiss_file in tqdm(faiss_files, 'Deserializing Embeddings...'):
            # Load the serialized document entry
            with open(faiss_file, 'rb') as f:
                doc_entry = pickle.load(f)

            # Populate the DocumentIngestor attributes with the deserialized information
            di.sources.append(doc_entry['source'])
            di.doc_chunks.append(doc_entry['chunks'])
            di.vector_stores.append(doc_entry['store'])

        if verbose:
            print(f'{di}')
            print(f' Done deserializing embeddings.')

        return di


if __name__ == "__main__":
    project_path = r'S:'
    input_path = os.path.join(project_path, '_data', 'pdfs')
    store_path = os.path.join(project_path, '_data', 'embeddings')
    model_path = os.path.join(project_path, '_data', 'models')

    di = DocumentIngestor(input_path, store_path, model_path)
    di.load_documents()
    di.generate_embeddings()
    faiss_dir = di.serialize_embeddings()

    di2 = DocumentIngestor.deserialize_embeddings(faiss_dir)
```

Comment: Try this:
raw_documents = loader.load_and_split()
instead of raw_documents = loader.load()